# Error splitting text by newline

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, opengl-es, webgl

This is relevant portion of my code:

```
ajax({
    url: "TeaPot.obj",
    success: function(data) {
        var Script = data.split("\n");
        for (var I in Script) {
        var Line = Script[I];
        console.log(Line);
        //If Vertice Line
        if (Line.substring(0, 2) == "v ") {
        //console.log("CORRECT");
            var Row = Line.substring(2).split(" ");
            console.log(Row[0]);
            verts[verts.length] = new Vector3(parseFloat(Row[0]),parseFloat(Row[1]), parseFloat(Row[2]));
        }
      }
```

Now this should go through each line and look for "v ", but my verts array still has nothing, any reason why?

oohh also the obj file looks abit like this

```
 v  -0.3393 0.0000 -12.3639
 v  1.8409 3.7515 -8.3253
```

I now have it so it will bring the length of verts to 96 which is correct, but the array has nothing stored???

```
            newX = parseFloat(row[1]);
            newY = parseFloat(row[2]);
            newZ = parseFloat(row[3])
            verts.push = new Vector3(newX, newY, newZ);
            console.log(verts[verts.length-1]);
```

Answer (score 4):

- `data` is a string, the content of the response.
- `data.responseText` is `undefined`.
- `data.responseText.split` is an exception, you cannot access properties of `undefined`.

You want this:

```
// save capital letter variables for constructors
var script = data.split("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

It thinks that the **responseText** property of **data** is undefined. I would set a breakpoint using firebug at the "var Script = ..." line and inspect what the value of **data** is at that point. If you can't set a breakpoint, do a simple **alert(data);** before that line to see what the value of **data** is. I suspect that **data** is raw text.